# angularjs service not populating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

Why is the `$sope.b` not being populated?

I'm trying to reach to the JSON that is received from the `$http` in the service through the service but it appears always as undefined I've added a snapshot of the output.

```
var app= angular.module("myApp");
app.service('RepoService', function($http){
   this.data= function(callBack){
    $http.get('/Data/list.json')
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
            callBack(response.data);
        })
    }
 })
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
 myApp.controller('listCtrl',function($scope,RepoService){
   RepoService.data(function(callBack){
   console.log(callBack) 
   $scope.b = callBack   
 });
  console.log("this is b =" +$scope.b);
 })
 [Somehow its always 'undefined'][1]
```

Comment: Introduce $timeout in your service and the try this when you are printing $scope.b . 

" $timeout( function(){ console.log("this is b =" +$scope.b); }, 3000);"

Comment: tried, with no success my guess is that I've async problem

Comment: Yes. That is what my assumption is. To avoid the async issue we can take help of the timeout. You may try to increase the timeout from 3000 to more.